# Get selected value from CHtml::dropDownList

Tags: php, yii

I have a question about Yii framework.

Let's say I have dropdown list like the code listed below.

I need to print selected value and I try to do it with `$_POST['countries']` 
but nothing happened.

I just need the selected value to store in a variable so I can manipulate it.

```
<?php 
      echo CHtml::dropDownList('countries', $select = array(),
      CHtml::listData($countries, 'code', 'name'));
?>
```

Comment: You want to print the selected value after pressing the submit button or just after the user selected it? Cuz in one case you r goign to use php and in the other javascript!

Comment: just after the user selected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_POST` var is corresponding to some data sent using `HTTP protocol`, so to use this var the client (the browser) need to send data to the server.

Since you want to display something just after the user selected a value in the dropdown list, you'll need to use javascript which is executed on the client side.

Here's an example that will get the selected value using jquery. You should then update the div where you want the value to appear, but since it's not in your question I can't help!

```
$('#dropDownId').change(function(){ 
    var value = $('#dropDownId :selected').text();
    //Here update the div where you need to see the selected value
});
```

Where `dropDownId` is the id that you need to give to your dropDownList (in the [CHtml::dropDownList html options](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail))

Comment: You could use .on('change', ..); as well

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an Ajax request. Its even better if you want to make some dependent dropdown lists.
For example:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($profile, $field->varname,CHtml::listData(Countries::model()->findAll(),'short','title'), array(
    'class'=>"chzn-select",
    'empty'=>"Select country",  
    'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url'=>$this->createUrl('registration/state'),   
                    'update' => '#Profile_state',                        
                    'data'=>array('country'=>'js:this.value',), 
                    'success'=> 'function(data) {
                                    $("#Profile_state").empty();
                                    $("#Profile_state").append(data);
                                    $("#Profile_state").trigger("liszt:updated");

                                            } ',

    )));
```

Then in your controller you can use POST 
Example:

```
    public function actionState()
{

 $data=Regions::model()->findAll('country_code=:country_code', 
                  array(':country_code'=> $_POST['country']));                
 echo "<option value=''>Select state</option>";
    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'region_code','region_title');
            foreach($data as $value=>$state)  {
                        echo CHtml::tag
                                ('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($state),true);
                    }   

}
```